# VBA Excel - Extend Formulas Down (Complicated)

Tags: excel, vba, relative-path

**Scenario:**

I have a consistent formula starting in `Range("V4")`.

This range has a *Defined Name*: **Stock4** (This is so the formula/cell can be relatively referenced if the user adds or removes surrounding columns).

The spreadsheet is constantly updated with fresh data (Pasted in `Range("A4:U4")`).

The amount of pasted rows varies with each batch of data.

I need to extend the formula within **Stock4** down to the last row...

**What I'm doing:**

So, I'm using a combination of...

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

And

```
.AutoFill Destination:=Range(*insert range here*), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

And my cell's *Defined Name*: **Stock4**.

**Here is what I get:**

```
Range("Stock4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Stock4:$V" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This works very well, however...

```
$V
```

...is not relative.

**My attempted solutions:**

I have tried using `Split(ActiveCell.Address(1, 0), "$")(0) & Lastrow`

This returns the `ActiveCell` *Column Letter*: **V** and `Lastrow` *Row Number*: **4831**.

However...

I can't simply substitute this code into my existing code in place of `$V" & Lastrow` (*see below*)

```
Range("Stock4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Stock4:Split(ActiveCell.Address(1, 0), "$")(0) & Lastrow"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

*Syntax errors aside, this simply won't work*.

**Question:**

How can I extend the formula located in **Stock4** down to the last row of *Stock4's* column (relative reference) using `VBA code`.

(This `code` is then going to be adapted and repeated for multiple relative columns across multiple spreadsheets)

**To sum up:**

Extend Formulas Down To Lastrow Using Defined Name Ranges And Relative Columns.
(I have spent the best part of 2 working days going grey with this problem - Is it possible? **It must be possible!**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass it to a variable and use this notation:

```
Sub MrJ()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("Stock4")
rng.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rng.Address, Cells(lastrow, rng.Column))
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe rng.Column returns the first column of rng. You would want Rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1

Comment: @WillHinsa I was under the impression that the range was a single cell and we were filling down.

Comment: Actually, it looks like my code isn't right either. OP wants the formula to be filled in $V, which from the example range ending in $U, You would want both columns on the autofill to be Rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count

Comment: @Raystafarian is correct, single cell only, filling down a relative column (in this example $V)

Comment: @Will Hinsa Range("A4:U4") is merely the pasted data and completely separate to the 'constant' formula located in 'Stock4'.

Comment: @Raystafarian - Your code seems to work perfectly! I will poke and probe it tomorrow but after a quick test it's exactly the idea I was looking for, many thanks.